# Make page url to be page title

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

What would be the easiest way to make a page title to be the url?

Currently I have:

```
http://localhost:53379/Home/Where
http://localhost:53379/Home/About
http://localhost:53379/Home/What
```

and would like to have

```
http://localhost:53379/where-to-buy
http://localhost:53379/about-us
http://localhost:53379/what-are-we
```

I thought about adding a `route` to each page (there's only 9 pages) but I wonder if there's something better, for example for big sites.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "where-to-buy",
    defaults: new { 
           controller = "Home", 
           action = "Where", 
           id = UrlParameter.Optional 
    }
);
...
```

and I would like to have it in English and Local language as well, so adding more routes would not make that much sense...

Answer (score 1):

If you need to fetch pages dynamically from the database, define a new route which will catch all requests. This route should be defined last.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Dynamic",
    url: "{title}",
    defaults: new { 
           controller = "Home", 
           action = "Dynamic", 
           title = ""
    }
)
```

Then in your controller:

```
public class HomeController {
    public ActionResult Dynamic(string title) {
         // All requests not matching an existing url will land here.

         var page = _database.GetPageByTitle(title);
         return View(page);
    }
}
```

Obviously all pages need to have a title (or slug, as it's commonly referred to) defined.

---

If you have static actions for each page, you could use [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/). It will allow you to specify the route for each action using an attribute:

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    [GET("Sample")]
    public ActionResult Index() { /* ... */ }

    [POST("Sample")]
    public ActionResult Create() { /* ... */ }

    [PUT("Sample/{id}")]
    public ActionResult Update(int id) { /* ... */ }

    [DELETE("Sample/{id}")]
    public string Destroy(int id) { /* ... */ }

    [Route("Sample/Any-Method-Will-Do")]
    public string Wildman() { /* ... */ }
}
```

I use it on a mid-sized project and it's working pretty well. The big win is that you always know where your routes are defined.

Comment: that will not help for dynamic page titles ... I can't have two routes with different names :/ and names should came from database, not hard coded, right?

Comment: @balexandre Well, that depends on your requirements. If you need to fetch titles from a database, set up a route which will catch all requests and then check if there are any matching pages in the database. Will update my answer.